# How do I use FireDAC DBMS identifiers to conditionally change SQL text

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to use the FireDac preprocessor to tailor the SQL text to the database server, however the text for all server types is included in the query text, so I assume I am either missing a setting or I need to call a method to process the text.

This is a simplified example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Conn: TFDConnection;
  Qry: TFDQuery;
  IdParam: TFDParam;
begin
  Conn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    Conn.ConnectionString := 'DriverID=PG;Server=localhost;Database=postgres;User_Name=user;Password=pass;';
    Conn.Connected := True;

    Qry := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      Qry.Connection := Conn;

      Qry.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO people (name) VALUES (:name) ' +
        '{IF MSSQL} select :id = @@identity {FI}' +
        '{IF PG} returning id {INTO :id} {FI}';

      Qry.ParamByName('name').AsString := 'George Smith';

      IdParam := Qry.ParamByName('id');
      IdParam.ParamType := ptOutput;
      IdParam.DataType := ftInteger;

      Qry.Prepare;
      Qry.ExecSQL;

      ShowMessage(IntToStr(IdParam.AsInteger));
    finally
      Qry.Free;
    end;

  finally
    Conn.Free;
  end;
end;
```

when Prepare is called the following error occurs:

> [FireDAC][Phys][PG][libpq] ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"

Thanks!

Comment: In the case of `MSSQL`, you are going to need a `;` between the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation:

[Preprocessing Command Text (FireDAC)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC))

> Setting the `CommandText` or `SQL` property values automatically fills the `Macros` collection property when the `ResourceOptions.MacroCreate` property is set to True. **When calling `Prepare`, the FireDAC command preprocessor transforms the command text into a form understood by the DBMS when [`ResourceOptions.MacroExpand`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.MacroExpand) is True.** This means the macros are not visible to the DBMS.

So make sure that [`ResourceOptions.MacroExpand`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.MacroExpand) is set to True.  And same with [`ResourceOptions.PreprocessCmdText`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.PreprocessCmdText), too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remy, I've updated the ResourceOptions on both the connection and query and unfortunately still get the same error.