# FireDAC DBMS Identifiers for conditional statement

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm trying to use the FireDAC DBMS Identifiers for generating a database specific query.
I'm connecting to a MySQL-Server currently (DriverID = `MySQL`). I want to query either from mysql or mssql with a `limit` / `top` query.
My current statement looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  {IF MSSQL} TOP(1) {fi} `tr`.`TaxRate_Primkey` 
FROM 
  `tbl_taxrates` AS `tr` 
WHERE 
  `tr`.`TaxRate_TaxCodeId` = `tc`.`TaxCode_Primkey` 
AND 
  `tr`.`TaxRate_ValidSince` <= :DATE 
ORDER BY `tr`.`TaxRate_ValidSince` DESC 
{IF MySQL} LIMIT 1 {fi}
```

Of course I'm aware, that the escaping will not be correct for mssql, but that's a different story.
When I inspect the FireDAC Monitor the preprocessed query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
   TOP(1)  `tr`.`TaxRate_Primkey` 
FROM 
  `tbl_taxrates` AS `tr` 
WHERE 
  `tr`.`TaxRate_TaxCodeId` = `tc`.`TaxCode_Primkey` 
AND 
  `tr`.`TaxRate_ValidSince` <= ? 
ORDER BY 
  `tr`.`TaxRate_ValidSince` DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Of course this will result in error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`TaxRate_Primkey` FROM `tbl_taxrates` AS `tr` WHERE `tr`.`TaxRate_TaxCodeId` ' at line 1 [errno=1064, sqlstate="42000"]
```

since it should only add the `LIMIT 1` and omit the `TOP(1)`.

Since I only have the Delphi Community Edition 10.4, I don't have access to the MSSQL-Driver. I thought, that could cause this error and I tried with others. But also with `{if FIREBIRD}` and `{if ADS}` it was the same.

The constructor looks like this:

```pascal
constructor TFireDACTenantRepository.Create(
  ADBName: string;
  ADBServer: string;
  APort: Integer;
  AUserName: string;
  APassword: string;
  ALogger: TLogger
);
var
  oParams: TStrings;
begin
  inherited Create;

  FLogger := ALogger;
  Self.MonitorLink := nil;
  Self.MonitorBy := mbRemote;
  Self.Tracing := True;

  FConnection := TFDConnection.Create(nil);

  oParams := TStringList.Create;
  try
    oParams.Add('Server=' + ADBServer);
    oParams.Add('Port=' + IntToStr(APort));
    oParams.Add('Database=' + ADBName);
    oParams.Add('User_Name=' + AUserName);
    oParams.Add('Password=' + APassword);
    oParams.Add('OSAuthent=No');
    FDManager.AddConnectionDef('MySQLConnectionTenant', 'MySQL', oParams);
    FConnection.Params.MonitorBy := Self.MonitorBy;
    FConnection.ConnectionDefName := 'MySQLConnectionTenant';
    FConnection.ResourceOptions.ParamCreate := True;
    FConnection.ResourceOptions.MacroCreate := True;
    FConnection.ResourceOptions.ParamExpand := True;
    FConnection.ResourceOptions.MacroExpand := True;
    FConnection.ResourceOptions.PreprocessCmdText := True;
    FConnection.ResourceOptions.EscapeExpand := True;
  finally
    oParams.Free;
  end;

  FConnection.AfterConnect := DoAfterConnect;
  FConnection.AfterDisconnect := DoAfterDisconnect;
end;
```

My question looks a bit related to this question here
[How do I use FireDAC DBMS identifiers to conditionally change SQL text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174389/how-do-i-use-firedac-dbms-identifiers-to-conditionally-change-sql-text)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If you want to use the conditional escape sequence, you also have to `use` the `FireDAC.Phys.XXX` unit for all involved databases.
Since I want to use MSSQL, I have to add `FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL` to the `use`-clause.

The units are listed here:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Databases_(FireDAC)

Maybe this answer helps others.

Comment: Wow, that's an ugly one....